# How to set two elements on the same line using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
.image{
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Currently I have 2 images  with the same size and I would like to equally let them share the screen. The img a on left handside and img b at right. The problem is if I set it as class, the two images is overlapped even I use inline - block. The restriction is I can not use relative. Therefore, is there any way to achieve this? Do I need to set a id for each image to do this? Thanks

Comment: or I need to use div to divde them instead of image?

Comment: Did you try using float: left property? It will push the second image to the right of the first image.

Comment: your problem is the `position:absolute`

Comment: Is seems nothing has changed... and currently the img b is on top of img a

Comment: but When I change to relative, I can not print it..

Comment: it display on screen correctly but when i print it it is a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to make it that their width shares 50% of the viewport, and height is 100% of the viewport? That can be achieved this way:

HTML:

```
<img src="source.html" />
<img src="source.html" />
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

img {
    ​width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UrfTu/)

Comment: thanks, but when I print the webpage, I use relative it does not have any thing display

Comment: What do you mean "use relative"?

Comment: set position : relative for img class

Comment: Why are you setting `position:relative`? With this approach you do not need to use that

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code I have tried.

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://www.rational-animal.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Facebook-logo-small-300x300.png" height="100" width="100" />
    <img src="http://www.rational-animal.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Facebook-logo-small-300x300.png" height="100" width="100" />
</div>
```

And this will be the CSS

```
img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block
}
```

[image]

The above result. Is that what you are looking for?

PS: Your images are getting overlapped because of absolute positioning.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but when I print the webpage, I use relative it does not have any thing display

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: divide the screen with two image, and print them